# Buildozer requires a python-for-android version with AAB (Android App Bundle) support

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, python-for-android

I'm having this error when I run buildozer:

`This buildozer version requires a python-for-android version with AAB (Android App Bundle) support. Please update your pinned version accordingly.`

But both my buildozer and my python-for-android are up to date (latter should have AAB).

In many places there's a solution to this problem to change p4a.branch in the spec-file but this does not change anything for me.